# CSS scroll-snap with Chrome

Tags: css, angular, polyfills, scroll-snap

I use CSS scroll-snap in my Angular application to scroll from section 1 to 2 etc. It works perfectly fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome it is jumping too far and always skipping one section (when using the mouse for scrolling, using the touchpad it works as expected).

So far, I have figured out that it is because the container element has `position: absolute` set. This is required.

Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/smrtny/pen/RwazzJX)

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999999999999;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
  scrollbar-width: none !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 530px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.section {
  height: 500px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">1</div>
  <div class="section">2</div>
  <div class="section">3</div>
  <div class="section">4</div>
  <div class="section">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share angular code as well?

Comment: Hi @prathameshk73, I added a codepen. There is no logic code specific to Angular

Comment: I am running your code from chrome and the effect is as desired. Maybe you have angular logic that interferes with the good behavior of the scroll-snap?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue on Chrome and Opera. Works fine in Edge and Firefox.

Comment: It is working fine for me in Chrome if I scroll via scrollpad on my laptop but when I use a mouse it is skipping the sections. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bru17 no there is no Angular logic interfering with this